# Using grep with a complex string

Tags: bash, grep

I am looking in the content of several files for strings like:

```
(2E)-3-({5,6-dihydroxy-3-methyl-2-oxo-4-[(1E)-prop-1-en-1-yl]-2,3-dihydro-1-benzofuran
```

with grep, so I try to do:

```
grep -n "(2E)-3-({5,6-dihydroxy-3-methyl-2-oxo-4-[(1E)-prop-1-en-1-yl]-2,3-dihydro-1-benzofuran" *.data
```

but I get errors, probably due to the fact that the string is complex.

Are there additional grep options or another way for me to find this string in the files?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't have my man pages to hand, but have you tried `grep -F`? I think it turns off regexp and treats the pattern as a fixed string. `fgrep` does the same.

Comment: +1 (checked from the manpage, `grep -F` is shorthand for `--fixed-string`)